# Comma inside inverted commas in an IF statement

Tags: worksheet-function

In the formula, IF[1000,",",1/3*27]

Please can you let me know what the **","** represents?

Comment: Those things that you call inverted commas are commonly known as quotes.  As the name suggests, they are used for specifying text constants, also known as strings.  So, for example, `42` is 2×3×7, but `"42"` is a string that is two characters long.  `TRUE` and `FALSE` are valid constant values in Excel, but `cat` and `dog` are not.  To use them in expressions/formulas, you would need to say `"cat"` and `"dog"`.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  P.S. Excel doesn't normally use square brackets (`[` and `]`) like that; `IF(…, …, …)` would be much more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Microsoft Excel, the "," in your formula indicates that the function will return the string `,` if 1000 is true (which upon testing happens to be true).

> [Microsoft Excel - IF function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
>   Use the IF function, one of the logical functions, to return one value
>   if a condition is true and another value if it's false.
>
> Syntax:  IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])

Answer (score 0):

It means if 1000 then insert comma, else insert <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> times 27 (or <sup>27</sup>/<sub>3</sub> = 9). Why it wasn't written as 27/3 or just 9 is beyond me.

Comment: It doesn't test for `cell = 1000 `, just tests 1000, which is true by definition

Comment: @MátéJuhász, you are absolutely correct. My answer was poorly written and has been edited. Thanks.